# The functionalities of two lines of code

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning about the threads in Java. I want to know whether the following two pieces of code are the same:

```
 class B extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }
    public void doSomething() {}
}
class A extends Thread { 
    public void run() {
        new B().start();
    }
}
```

The second piece of code is changing the class A:

```
class A extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            new B().doSomething();
        }
}
```

When I read the code of my team's project, I find this problem: A thread invoking another thread without loop.

Comment: It is not clear what the last line you wrote means.

Comment: they are the last line@eznme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two cases are not the same, as your question already suggests.

Assuming that in each case we enter the code by calling `new A().start()`, then the first example starts a thread (A) which starts another thread (B) which calls `doSomething()`.

The second case starts a single thread (A) which calls `B.doSomething()`. In this case we don't start a thread of type B, because we never call `.start()` on an instance of B.

Comment: if they are the last line , the result will be same ?

Comment: In both cases, `doSomething()` will be called once, so the apparent result will be the same, but the number of threads started will be different. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Is the second better?

Comment: Probably - it is more efficient in that it doesn't start an unnecessary thread. However, you could probably simplify further by moving `doSomething()` into A, and eliminating B altogether.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet you are actually creating a new thread and the invocation of doSomething() is in a separate thread to what A's run() method is running in,

In the second snippet you are execution B's doSomething() in the context (thread) that A is running in.